# C# .Net web service handle 3 nested response

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, webservice-client

My soap endpoint adress returns soap response like that and .net can not serialize  the **queryParameter** **queryParameter** **queryParameter** levels.
It returns as null.

How can we fix this problem?

```
<ResultInfos>
    <ResultInfos>
        <queryParameter>
            <queryParameter>
                <queryParameter>
                    <parameterFormat/>
                    <parameterName/>
                    <parameterType>dfgsfgsd</parameterType>
                    <parameterValue>2342234</parameterValue>
                </queryParameter>
                <queryParameter>
                    <parameterFormat/>
                    <parameterName/>
                    <parameterType>safd</parameterType>
                    <parameterValue>234234</parameterValue>
                </queryParameter>
                <queryParameter>
                    <parameterFormat/>
                    <parameterName/>
                    <parameterType>sfsdf</parameterType>
                    <parameterValue>3454</parameterValue>
                </queryParameter>
                <queryParameter>
                    <parameterFormat/>
                    <parameterName/>
                    <parameterType>234234</parameterType>
                    <parameterValue>A</parameterValue>
                </queryParameter>                 
            </queryParameter>
        </queryParameter>
    </ResultInfos>
</ResultInfos>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will edit the reference.cs that .net produce. .Net can not handle that kind of response. We will help it.

Open your web service reference.cs and add these lines to top of your class. 
In our case queryparameter[][].

Keyword is **NestingLevel** attirabute .

```
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("queryParameter", Namespace = "http://wsserver", IsNullable = false)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("queryParameter", Namespace = "http://wsserver", IsNullable = false, NestingLevel = 1)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("queryParameter", Namespace = "http://wsserver", IsNullable = false, NestingLevel = 2)]
    public QueryParameter[][] queryParameter {
        get {
            return this.queryParameterField;
        }
        set {
            this.queryParameterField = value;
        }
    }
```